# Displaying either checkbox or button based on condition using Kendo grid Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo Grid where on each row I am able to get both checkbox and button on a grid cell, but I want to know is there a way to get either checkbox or button(not both) based on any condition on same grid row, like assume first row i need only checkbox, second and third row i need only button, fourth only checkbox and so on..., currently i am able to get both checkbox and button on a cell i need either one of them not both

**CODE**

```
columns: [
                { field: "ID", Title: "ID", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },

                { field: "RowID", Title: "RowID", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },

                { field: "BillNumber", Title: "BillNumber", filterable: false, sortable: false, hidden: true },

                { field: "ServiceName", Title: "ServiceName", width: 600 },

                { field: "ServiceStatus", Title: "ServiceStatus", width: 150 },
                {
                   template: '<input type=\"checkbox\" #=data.Action ? checked="checked" : "" #  class=\"check_row\"/> <input type="button" class="k-button info" name="info" value="Info" />',
                   headerTemplate: '<label>  <input type="checkbox" id="checkAll"/>Print All</label>', filterable: false, sortable: false, width: 100,
               }
            ]
        });
```

Comment: I think here you might have to use **dataBound** event like this - dataBound: function(e) { your code goes here }

Comment: Krishnraj Rana, thanks for your reply, I am able to get now, without using dataBound, but i have one question, while using <script lang="javascript" type="text/kendo-template"></script>, on type="text/kendo-template", text/kendo-template is not predicting(not listed) as text/javascript do, am i missing any src path ?? have any idea ??

Comment: I just drafted my answer and got your comment. Anyways its great u got the solution. You have not find it in predicting list bcs its not standard. No you have not missing any thing.. :)

Comment: ok,how can i use 2 different script one is of type"text/javascript" and text/kendo-template" ?? I am working on MVC, so in CSHTML, the code inside "text/kendo-template" dont seems to be working, got any idea ??

Comment: First what i m suggesting you is if you got the solution of your above question then its better you post it as answer, so when other people comes to this question, they'll get the idea.

Comment: its not the different question i asked Krishnraj, i am on same page, i would able to get button and checkbox, but onclick is not working, so it should work on implementing the "text/kendo-template" code, that's why I asked, anyways thanks for your reply :)